# Xml parsing includes inline parsing

Tags: java, xml

Using:

```
 import org.w3c.dom.*;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
 import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
```

how can i extract xml data? for example for this xml file:

```
<request method="POST" url="/devices/test/planner" body="*">
  <response statusCode="200">
    <header>
      <headerParameters>
        <headerParameter name="Content-Type">Content-Type=application/xml</headerParameter>
      </headerParameters>
    </header>
    <body>booking created!</body>
  </response>
</request>
```

how do i extract the data simply?
Also how can i extract data from inline row?

```
<request method="POST" url="/devices/test/planner" body="*">
```

Thanks?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You've just said what classes you intend to use. And what do you mean by "data [in an] inline row"?

Comment: I tried using some libreries counting on tutoriels, but only managed to get part of the parsing. in every tutoriel they use diffrent libraries and i cant get the one that covers all i need (or propably i cant figure out the tools an api i can use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second the recommendation to use XPath. You could manually traverse the DOM, but why? XPath was designed to solve this problem. Here's a complete Java/[JAXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing)/XPath example (*sans* error-checking and exception handling):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Xpather {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, 
            SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource("workbook.xml"));
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Node body = (Node) xpath.evaluate("/request/response/body", doc,
                XPathConstants.NODE);
        System.out.println(body.getTextContent());
        Node url = (Node) xpath.evaluate("/request/@url", doc,
                XPathConstants.NODE);
        System.out.println(url.getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

This code prints the contents of the `body` element and the value of the `url` attribute on the `request` element.

Output:

> booking created!
>
> /devices/test/planner

Answer (score 1):

Use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) - also readily available through [standard Java APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).  Once you have your `Document`, Java's XPath can evaluate directly off of it - so having your `DocumentBuilder` and such will still be used.

For example, you can obtain just the `<request/>` element, using `/request`, or the request's URL, using something like `/request/@url`.

An alternative - especially for high-performance usage scenarios where you may be processing many documents following the same schema - is to use SAX parsing instead, where you will receive an event for every XML element processed, and given its name and list of attributes.

Comment: Now that StAX is around, there's probably very very few use cases where SAX would be a better choice. (It's also a very vague recommendation.)